# Question about the application of continuous functions and IVT

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I came across a question which says:

> Suppose that $f:[0,2 \pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and $f(0)=f(2 \pi)$.
>
> 1.Show that there exists $x \in [0,\pi]$ such that $f(x)=f(x+ \pi)$.
>
> 2.Explain why this means that on any circle on the surface of the earth, there is a pair of opposite points such that the air temperature at the two points are equal.
>
> 3.Is it also true that on any circle on the surface of the earth, there is a pair of opposite points where the age of the surface rock is the same?

I did the first part of the question by letting $g(x)=f(x)-f(x+ \pi)$, since $g$ is continuous I used the intermediate value theorem to prove that there exists $x \in (0, \pi)$ such that $g(x)=0$.

Then for the second part, I assumed that the air temperature can be written as a continuous function $t:[0,2 \pi] \to \mathbb{R}$, and then applied part 1.

However, I am not sure what to do with the third part of the question, should I assume another continuous function for the age of the surface rock, or is the third part different from the second part, and it is not possible to assume that the age of rock is continuous.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Who knows? But since you can have a volcano forming a patch of brand new rock among older ones, maybe you are supposed to assume it is not continuous.

Comment: The follow-up problems that I have usually seen for this problem is to ask: `Are there always antipodal points in the globe such that both temperature and air pressure are the same?` Or similar statements with a pair of continuous magnitudes.